# Auto-py-to-exe won't open correctly

Tags: python, auto-py-to-exe

I have tried to pip install auto-py-to-exe and i got an error with the "gevent" so I installed gevent 1.4.0 and then I could install auto-py-to-exe(2.5.2), but when i'm trying to open it I get this window:

[image]

My network is an enternal network so I dont have accses to the newest version.

Comment: to what newest version don't you have access? you just said you used `pip` to install so you definitely can get the latest version, anyways, did you check the proxy and firewall as the error message suggests?

Comment: Im using pip that get access to website which there the packeges coming from, its not connected to the web. I'm using my compeny network, which is closed netwrok, so of course I dont hace acceses to the interent, the problem start that the auto-py-to-exe wont open as gui progrem but as html

Answer (score 0):

You can install the program with"

```
pip install auto-py-to-exe
```

URL: https://pypi.org/project/auto-py-to-exe/

Or you can directly get sourcecode from: https://github.com/brentvollebregt/auto-py-to-exe

Master: https://github.com/brentvollebregt/auto-py-to-exe/archive/refs/heads/master.zip